# WCF service and stored proc to poll data Asynchronously

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf

I basically have a Silverlight web application, I'm busy implementing a WCF service which will call a stored proc in SQL Server and get the rows. However I need to poll this data every few seconds since the data will be updating every second in the database.

Was wondering what is the best way to approach this:

1. having a timer, which will call the service after certain duration and updating
2. implementing the polling on the WCF service side? Which I'm not sure on how to approach that and if it is possible.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Cheers,
Michelle

Comment: I don't know how you would do this "on the WCF service side" - having a timer in your client app seems like the much easier approach....

Answer (score 1):

You can try the option of calling the wcf service asynchronously from the client. Refer this msdn article. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730059.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply Aravind, that could work, so correct me if i am wrong so for each second ticked on the timer i will be calling my wcf service asynch which in turn will called the stored proc on the database

Comment: Whenever you want to hit the database you need to call the wcf service method. you need to write your event in such fashion.